# Ember passing multiple list items in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Is it possible to pass multiple list of items in template using {{each}}

Can someone guide me on what I am doing, 
in my sales-orders.hbs below is my currenet code.

```
    {{#each model as |detail|}}
        <li>{{sales-orders-grid detail=detail}}</li>
    {{else}}
      Blank
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Then calling the sales-orders-grid component

```
Shipping Method
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 products-item-products border-left padding10">
        <ul>
            {{#each shippingMethod as |sm|}}
                {{sales-orders-grid-shipping-method sm=sm}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

In my sales-orders-grid-shipping-method component calling is this:

```
sm.shippingMethodName
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to pass list of items in {{each}} in my main template. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is it possible to pass multiple list in template using {{each}} for example 
{{#each model, list1, list2 as | model, list1, list2 |}}
{{index-listing model=model, list1=list1, list2=list}}
{{/each}}

I'm trying to display a grid using the passed data.
SO, model[0]  = list1[0] = list2[0], 
 model[1] = list1[1] = list2[1],
model[2] = list1[2] = list2[2]
and so on.

I know its pretty ugly, will improve it some other time but for now that's the only solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

To change scope you can use the "with" helper.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_with

```
{{#with user.posts as |blogPosts|}}
  <div class="notice">
    There are {{blogPosts.length}} blog posts written by {{user.name}}.
  </div>
  {{#each blogPosts as |post|}}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

I think you can nest multiple "with" helper.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to restructure your data as:model.list1,model.list2,etc.
Then pass the model and use as necessary.And use nested each to acheive the grid.
Iam only posting this as an answer because I can't comment yet.
So, do get back to me for Clarifications.